# ListBox not databinding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, .net-4.5

My `ListBox` control is working fine, except that the data to be bound is not displaying.

My XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listFileNames" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Height="50"></Image>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=State}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="This text shows..."></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

My code:

```
public struct StyleDocumentFile
{
    public string Image;
    public string FileName;
    public string State;
}

// ......

StyleDocumentFile sdf = new StyleDocumentFile()
{
    Image = "/Images/Loading.png",
    FileName = "abc",
    State = "Extracting Data...",
};

this.listFileNames.Items.Add(sdf);
```

Comment: Are there any messages in the Debug window?

Comment: There were yes. I didn't realize WPF did that. Said the properties could not be found. ebattulga below found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change fields to Property. After this, all works fine.

```
public struct StyleDocumentFile
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `ItemsSource` in ListBox definition like `ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Items}"`. In addition you must call `RaisePropertyChanged` in `setter` of model properties.